# simplemodal not picking up data-height and data-width

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

In fact, I edited the sample HTML basic template from author Eric Martin and it dw.
**How come?** Here is the file: http://communitychessclub.com/basic/index.html and all needed files are clearly referenced correctly.

This the HTML to invoke the simplemodal:

```
<a href='#' class='basic' data-width="586" data-height="100">Demo</a>
```

This is the target div to popup:

```
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<p class="hyphenate"><span class="bold">George Carlin explains:</span> "Quality. Values. Style. Service. Selection. Convenience. Economy. Savings. Performance. Experience. Hospitality. Low rates. Friendly service. Name brands. Easy terms. Affordable prices. Money back guarantee. Free installation. Free admission. Free appraisal. Free delivery. Free alterations. Free home trial. And free parking.</p></div>
```

This is the javascript to process the modal:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    var hrefval= $(this).attr("href"); 
    var $this = $(this); 
    var height_len = $this.data("height");  
    var width_len = $this.data("width"); 

$('#basic-modal-content').modal(

containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#ccc",
        borderColor:"#ccc",
        border:5,
        padding:5,
        height:'height_len+20',
        width:'width_len+20'
        });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arent you missing a {} cus this gives an error:

```
missing ) after argument list
[Afbreken op deze fout] containerCss: {
```

It should be something around containerCss like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
        var hrefval = $(this).attr("href");
        var $this = $(this);
        var height_len = $this.data("height");
        var width_len = $this.data("width");

        $('#basic-modal-content').modal(
        {
            containerCss: {
                backgroundColor: "#ccc",
                borderColor: "#ccc",
                border: 5,
                padding: 5,
                height: height_len+20,
                width: width_len+20
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Update how to use multiple**

```
<a href='#' class='basic' data-connection="dialog1" data-width="586" data-height="100">Demo</a>
<a href='#' class='basic' data-connection="dialog2" data-width="586" data-height="100">Demo</a>
```

The Boxes

```
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="dialog1"><p class="hyphenate">BOX 1</p></div>
<div id="dialog2"><p class="hyphenate">BOX 2</p></div>
```

The script

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
        var hrefval = $(this).attr("href");
        var $this = $(this);
        var height_len = $this.data("height");
        var width_len = $this.data("width");
        var id = $this.data("connection")

        $('#' + id).modal(
        {
            containerCss: {
                backgroundColor: "#ccc",
                borderColor: "#ccc",
                border: 5,
                padding: 5,
                height: height_len+20,
                width: width_len+20
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! That fixed it, significantly. But the script doesn't pick up var height_len = $this.data("height"); and var width_len = $this.data("width"); -which is supposed to be passed by <a href='#' class='basic' data-width="586" data-height="100">Demo</a> Any thoughts?

Comment: You got quotes around height: 'height_len+20' and you should have height_len + 20 instead of quotes, remove them and I think it will work

Comment: You are right! Works fine now. Appreciated! Serious question now: I don't see how this script is useful in the sense that the target div always has to have an ID of "#basic-modal-content" Isn't there a more elegant way for <a href='#' class='basic' data-width="586" data-height="100">Demo</a> to call the target div and for "$('#basic-modal-content') to be an undefined class?

Comment: You can just change the model id to whatever you want as long as you change your DIV's ID aswell. In JS and HTML the ID's should be the same.

Comment: I'm confused. ID's must be be unique. Can't have <!-- modal content --> <div id="basic-modal-content"> for more than one <div> Does it need to be a class? If I make the HTML and JS ID's the same .. it isn't really programming, is it?

Comment: Yes ID's have to be unique, but if you want to have another modal box. If you make a class of "basic-modal-content" and change the # to a . in JS.

Comment: OK. I followed your instructions. Now... how do I create another modal popup?

Comment: Would it possible to use "data-href="some ID" and then ID a div with that correspondingly ID?

Comment: That's very nice! The remaining issue was the <div id='basic-modal'> which is referenced in the js as $('#basic-modal .basic') which I changed to $('.basic') and now it all look fine. Thank you !